# Traefik Ingress rewrite-target does nothing

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

I have a backend service which responds to `/` but I want it to run on the ingress route `myhost.com/overview`. No matter which configuration I try, traefik does not strip the path `/overview` away - I can see the backend getting `/overview`.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: registry-ingress
  namespace: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myhost.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /overview
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: overview
              port:
                number: 8079
```

I have tried several variations of this:

```yaml
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
...
        - path: /overview(.*)
```

But these lead to 404 on the ingress `/overview` requests do not reach the backend.

In summary I want `https://myhost.com/overview/` to hit the backend at `/`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Traefik does not support the `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation. See the list of available annotations here: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-ingress/#annotations

But your goal can be achieved using the [StripPrefix](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/stripprefix/) middleware.

```yaml
---
# Middleware
# Strip prefix /overview
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: mw-admin
  namespace: ingress
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    forceSlash: false
    prefixes:
      - /overview
---
# Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: registry-ingress
  namespace: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: ingress-mw-admin@kubernetescrd
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myhost.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: myhost.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /overview
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: overview
              port:
                number: 8079
```

Comment: To me, following was unclear - How to define this value? `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: ingress-mw-admin@kubernetescrd` I realized later that it is `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: <namespace>-<middlewarew_name>@kubernetescrd`. I hope this might help others.

Comment: works as a clock, thank you